# MinGW GCC.exe removing all \ from path

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I am not really sure what's going on here. I'm trying to compile https://github.com/LRN/libntlink so I can easily port this Unix call-reliant code (that project provides windows implementations of symlink() lstat() and macros like S_ISDIR.

Anyway, when I run the supplied cmd file (after changing the variables to point to the right path), I get this:

```
gcc  c:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.3\include;c:\MinGW\include -I. -O3 -fno-common
-Wall -mms-bitfields -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 -o juncpoint.o -c juncpoint.c
gcc.exe: error: c:MinGWlibgccmingw324.9.3include: No such file or directory
```

It seems like for some reason all \ are being totally removed from path sometime before gcc.exe parses it to find its stuff. The same thing is happening with c:\MinGW\include. I looked through the makefile, and although I have trouble reading it, I didn't see anything that seemed like it would cause this. This isn't my first time using MinGW, and although the first time failed too, it was for a different reason.

Comment: what shell are you using? Anyway, try with double slashes \\ or just use /

Comment: doing / worked. Different error now, but its at least further along, and I'm not stuck anymore, even if I might be again soon, but it seems like a different problem at least. Still very strange things happening. Lots of /../ being put in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the person who wrote the cmd put it in \ path form when it needed to be in / path form for the shell I was in. A different problem shows up now related to permission denied